# Question regarding k fold cross validation for KNN using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, knn

I am trying to fit 5 fold cross validation for several values of k. I used the OJ data set in ISLR package.

my code so far as follows,

```
library(ISLR)
library(class)
ks=c(1:5)
err.rate.test <- numeric(length = 5)
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(OJ)),breaks=5,labels=FALSE)

for (j in seq(along = ks)) {
  set.seed(123)
  cv.knn <- sapply(1:5, FUN = function(i) {
    testID <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE)
    test.X <- OJ[testID, 3]
    test.Y <- OJ[testID, 1]
    train.X <- OJ[-testID, 3]
    train.Y <- OJ[-testID, 1]
    knn.test <- knn(data.frame(train.X), data.frame(test.X), train.Y, k = ks[j])
    cv.test.est <- mean(knn.test != test.Y)
    return(cv.test.est)
  })
  err.rate.test[j] <- mean(cv.knn)

}


err.rate.test
[1] 0.3757009 0.3757009 0.3757009 0.3757009 0.3757009
```

The code doesn't give any errors. But for some reason , my test error rate for each value of k is same.This seems to be weird for me. So i assume there is something wrong with my code.

Can anyone help me to figure that out ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `set.seed(123)`, this causes the repeat error rates.

`set.seed` is used for reproducibility, ensuring that any random grid searches or parameter estimates remain constant, meaning all of the parameter estimates that go into fitting the `knn` model will be the same across executions, resulting in the same predictions and therefore the same error rates.